# Type does not implement Copy error when using supertrait of Copy in an enum

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I'm new to Rust traits, so this could be due to a misunderstanding of supertraits, `dyn` or anything else. I'm trying to use a trait object in an enum to:

- Put a trait bound on the concrete types that can be used in this element of the enum
- Make sure that the enum can still derive `Copy`

The minimal example (which fails to compile on [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b5a6b76829b376fca62f0274bc6b9cf5) with the relevant error) is:

```rust
#[derive(Copy)]
enum Foo {
    A,
    B(dyn MyTraitWhichIsCopy),
}

trait MyTraitWhichIsCopy: Copy {}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0204]: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type
 --> src/lib.rs:1:10
  |
1 | #[derive(Copy)]
  |          ^^^^
...
4 |     B(dyn MyTraitWhichIsCopy),
  |       ---------------------- this field does not implement `Copy`
  |
  = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0204`.
```

After invoking `rustc --explain E0204` I noticed the following, which might be where I'm hitting problems:

```
The `Copy` trait is implemented by default only on primitive types. If your
type only contains primitive types, you'll be able to implement `Copy` on it.
Otherwise, it won't be possible.
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems in the given code.

1. The trait `Clone` is not object-safe because the method `clone` refers to the raw self type, which is unknown through the `dyn` abstraction. Your trait has a super trait `Copy` and `Copy` has a super trait `Clone`, therefore your trait is not object-safe, which means it cannot be used as a trait object, which is also known as "`dyn` trait".
2. Trait object is `?Sized` which means it is a dynamic sized type (DST, whose size is unknown at compile time) that cannot be used as a enum field because it also makes the enum type `?Sized`. In most cases, DST can only be held through reference, practically `Box<dyn Trait>` when owned, otherwise `&dyn Trait` or `&mut dyn Trait`.
3. `Copy` requires super trait `Clone`, which means "any type that implements `Copy` must implement `Clone`". So when we wish our custom type to implement `Copy`, we should implement `Clone` first.

Conclusion: It is impossible to constraint a type to implement `Copy` or `Clone` through a trait object, and you must use a `Box` to hold your trait object, and use a manually defined clone instead of the standard clone trait and implement clone for the boxed trait object:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn clone_dyn(&self) -> Box<dyn MyTrait>;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyImpl;

impl MyTrait for MyImpl {
    fn clone_dyn(&self) -> Box<dyn MyTrait> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

impl Clone for Box<dyn MyTrait> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.clone_dyn()
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
enum Foo {
    A,
    B(Box<dyn MyTrait>),
}
```

Comment: Thanks - your reference to object safety was something I hadn't seen before and pointed me towards this [other helpful discussion](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/object-safety-and-cloning-traits/22620)

Comment: There is an [official document](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety). @Kyle_S-C

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic type bound by your trait. Also notice that you need `Clone` to have `Copy` too:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Foo<T: MyTraitWhichIsCopy> {
    A,
    B(T),
}

trait MyTraitWhichIsCopy: Copy {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be7af41559fe4e0d083deda8ef38fd02)

Comment: Thanks - I think there's another implicit requirement that I omitted - that you don't end up with separate instances of the enum, depending on which type you declare it with. Accordingly, I think Alsein's answer is closer to the problem I have.